# find message body reader for type: interface org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile of content type: multipart/form-data

Tags: java, spring

2023-04-07 12:42:01,316 ERROR org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n [http-nio-127.0.0.1-7080-exec-1] [] RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute
javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003200: Could not find message body reader for type: interface org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile of content type: multipart/form-data

in test method

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@ApiOperation(value = "Execute a get workflowInstanceId status")
public ResponseEntity uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
// elaborazione del file uploadato
String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
String contentType = file.getContentType();
// byte[] content = file.getBytes();
// ...
return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded successfully");
}